# Auto.Arima with Daily Sales - Univariate Time Series Error

Tags: r, arima

I'm working with a data set from 2017-01-01 to 2017-10-27, however, the `auto.arima` says it can only handle univariate time series, despite there being only daily data.

What am I missing?

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(25)
datelist<-seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"),as.Date("2017-10-27"),by="day")
salesvals<-round(abs(rnorm(length(datelist)))*1000,digits=2)
salestbl<-data.frame(datelist,salesvals)

salesTS<-ts(salestbl,
            start=c(2016,as.numeric(format(salestbl$datelist, "%j"))),
            frequency=7)
fit <- auto.arima(salesTS)
```

Error:

`Error in auto.arima(salesTS) : 
  auto.arima can only handle univariate time series`

Overall, I know there's a weekly seasonality, hence the seven days. I know there's also a quarterly seasonality, but I can tackle that another time.

Overall I'm trying to get a forecast for `2017-12-31`, using an arima forecast.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are declaring the `data.frame` as time series wrong. Any way you dont need to do that just omit the `ts` part like this:

```
set.seed(25)
datelist<-seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"),as.Date("2017-10-27"),by="day")
salesvals<-round(abs(rnorm(length(datelist)))*1000,digits=2)
salestbl<-data.frame(datelist,salesvals)

fit <- auto.arima(salestbl[,2])
```

just `head(salesTS)` and you will see why you get the error.